# Cannot inject factory into controller in Jasmine (requireJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have some issues injecting my factory into testing spec. I am using requireJS to inject controllers and factories etc.

```
    define(['controller', 'loginFactory', 'angular', 'angularMocks'],

      function(ctrl, loginFactory, angular){

        var scope,
            OnBoardingCtrl;

        describe('Controller: OnBoarding', function () {

          beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $location) {

            angular.module('app');

            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            OnBoardingCtrl = $controller(ctrl, {
              '$scope': scope,
              'loginFactory': loginFactory,
            });


          }));

      it('Should check endpoint', inject(function ($http, $httpBackend) {

        var successCallback = jasmine.createSpy();
        var url = 'login?un=test&pw=test';

        var response = {"token":1}

        $httpBackend.expectGET(url)
          .respond(200, response);

        $http.get(url).success(successCallback);

        expect(successCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(successCallback.token).toBe(1);

      }));
    });
  }
);
```

How ever I keep getting **TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'successCallback.token)** For reference my LoginFactory looks like this:

```
  var LoginFactory = function ($q, $http) {

    return {
      getData: function (url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://local/'+url)
          .then(function () {
            deferred.resolve(true);
          }, function () {
            deferred.resolve(false);
          });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };

  };

  LoginFactory.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];
  factories.factory('LoginFactory', LoginFactory);

  return LoginFactory;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you think `LoginService.$inject` should be `LoginFactory.$inject` ? We're specifying the dependencies for LoginFactory object not LoginService

Comment: Yes it should, I've updated

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned already, `successCallback.token` is the point where your code is breaking because `jasmine.createSpy()` returns a function but it has no clue about your `token` from your mock response served by `$httpBackend`. From the official [docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpy%3C/code%3E),

> When there is not a function to spy on, jasmine.createSpy can create a “bare” spy. 
>     This spy acts as any other spy – tracking calls, arguments, etc. 
>       But there is no implementation behind it. Spies are JavaScript objects 
>       and can be used as such.

So removing this line `expect(successCallback.token).toBe(1);` will resolve the error but if you actually want to verify the mock response from $httpBackend, you need to do that in `success` callback on $http (or) in the promise object's `then` method like below

```
 $http.get(url).success(function(response){
     expect(response.token).toBe(1);
 });
```

Note that here I just modified your code to show the example, ideally you don't code the HTTP call separately in your test case, you invoke the actual function making the HTTP call and verify the expectations.

For more details on `$httpBackend`, have a look at this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend).

Comment: Thanks. I understand that I should be making a request to the actual function making the HTTP request. However when I do so i.e. call LoginFactory.getData(url), it returns `undefined is not a function (evaluating...` which I assume is because it can't find the getData method?